# jQuery hide div when user clicks outside of another div

Tags: jquery

I know this question was asked manytimes, but my problem is somehow different.

this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8oqvoffc/

For those with same problem here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/8oqvoffc/4/ thanxs to MarcelD

So, if i click outside the main div it does hide the second div. However it shouldn't hide if I click inside the main div on some elements. Like other child DIV or P. It should only take affect when its clicked outside of its borders. Whats shall I change?

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'slide-out') {
    $('.totals').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.totals {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0px !important;
  background: #000 !important;
  right: 0px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 190px !important;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  z-index: 9999999999999999999999999 !important;
  display: ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide-out" class="div1">
  <div class="div1_one">
    sada
  </div>
  <p>
    hello world!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="totals">

</div>
```

Comment: you have a click listener on document... why don't just add the click listener to the element that should be able to be clicked?!

Comment: Is this what your looking for ? https://jsfiddle.net/g959Lkq9/

Comment: Not really. It does the same. If you click on lets say HELLO WORLD! It will also hide the .totals div. But it shouldn't. How to avoid this?

Comment: Try now https://jsfiddle.net/9L85oosf/

Comment: not working alt all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the parent(s) like @Carsten pointed out..
but his solution is just for one level...

here an updated fiddle + doesn't matter how deep your elements are -> as long as they have the parent #slide-out it won't hide your .totals

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {   
 if(e.target.id != 'slide-out' && $(e.target).parents('#slide-out').length === 0) {
        $('.totals').hide();   
    } 
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.totals {
   border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
   position:fixed !important;
   bottom: 0px !important;
   background: #000 !important;
   right: 0px !important;
   width: 300px !important;
   height: 190px !important;
   padding-top: 20px !important;
   z-index: 9999999999999999999999999 !important;
   display: ;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="slide-out" class="div1">
  <div class="div1_one">
  sada
  </div>
  <p>
  hello world!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="totals">

</div>
```

Cheerio :)

Comment: did u tried -> run code snippet? -> its working like expected -> as long as u click on something inside #slide-out nothing happens... so exactly how Andrew needs it: "...it shouldn't hide if I click inside the main div on some elements..."

Comment: Hello Marcel, I know my English is bad... But till now you are the only one who understood me. You got it RIGHT, except your code only needed small update. I added at the end "e.target.className != "totals"...

Comment: ahh thx for your hint @RanaGhosh #NOT - if my understanding is wrong - pls just shortly explain why... your understanding is wrong doesn't help anybody...

Comment: Thanks " $(e.target).parents('#slide-out').length === 0" was missing. You are my hero today! I was searching for solution for about 3 hours....

Comment: @MarcelD Ok, edit your answer. I will remove downvote. Because it's locked.

Comment: @RanaGhosh my answer was correct - so why should i edit?! - if you read the comments you will see that the AndrewS is pointing out that i got him correctly - his quote: "...you are the only one who understood me" ;)

Comment: @MarcelD Ya I know. I am just telling that my vote wast more that 15 minutes long. So, just change something '.' or anything then I can remove downvote from this answer. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stopPropagation()` function to stop the click event from firing through the child element to the parent

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'slide-out') {
    $('.totals').hide();
  }
});

$('.totals').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.div1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.totals {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0px !important;
  background: #000 !important;
  right: 0px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 190px !important;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  z-index: 9999999999999999999999999 !important;
  display: ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide-out" class="div1">
  <div class="div1_one">
    sada
  </div>
  <p>
    hello world!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="totals">
</div>
```

Comment: Not working if clicked on blank grayed portion which should work

Comment: Why dont i see an answer by you then? @RanaGhosh If you knew to read code, you will know only clicking on the black portion will stop the porpagation.

Comment: I already given a answer. Please check . ;) Your's is already right. That time not working because I was trying that in jsfiddle. Please Edit your answer. I will remove my Downvote. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already solved but the quickest and best solution for this is in below. I think should use this code. Don't want you to accept this answer but just trying to help you.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('body').not('.totals').click(function(e) {
        $('.totals').hide();
    })
});
```